# How to do email piping / forwarding in Centos Web Panel with CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I am trying to forward copy of emails to Osticket while retaining original in the mailbox in Centos Web Panel with CentOS 7

This is my script in \etc\postfix\master.cf -

```
whmcspipe unix - n n - - pipe 
  flags=Rq user=testuser argv=/usr/local/bin/php -q 
/home/testuser/public_html/crons/pipe.php -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

But this is deleting the original email in the mailbox.

Also how to forward email to another email in Centos Web Panel with CentOS 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way,

1)create email `osticketsupport@youdomain.tld`

2) create alias/forward `osticketsupport@youdomain.tld`  to `osticketsupport@youdomain.tld` and `osticketsupport1@youdomain.tld` using Centos Web Panel (Go to `Email` --> `Add Email account` and fill in the fields under `Create a New Email Alias (Forwarder)` form and save)

3) pipe osticketsupport1@youdomain.tld to osticket or other local script using method described in this link -
http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/postfix-pipe-email-to-whmcs-ticket